# drop down menu width arrangement

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, menu

I have a site of width 990px to view [Click Here](http://www.fedri.com/bh/). Just I install a multiple layer drop down menu. If you see on this site I have 6 categories on the drop down menu and after that a blank space. I want all the categories to arrange fully without space.

my css code is

```
  /* Page */
body,html,div,blockquote,img,label,p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,ul,ol,li,dl,dt,dd,form,a,fieldset,input,th,td{border:0;outline:none;margin:0;padding:0;}
ul{list-style:none;}

body {font: normal 13px Arial, sans-serif;}
h2 {font: normal 26px Arial, sans-serif; padding: 20px 0; margin: 0 0 30px 0;}
.wrap {width: 990px; margin: 0 auto;}
.demo-container {padding: 0 0;}
.demo-container h4 {font-size: 14px; margin: 0 0 5px 0;}

/* Mega Menu Styles */
.mega-menu ul, .mega-menu ul li {list-style: none;}
.mega-menu ul {position: relative; padding: 0; margin: 0;}
.mega-menu ul li ul {display: none;}
.mega-menu .sub {display: none;}
.mega-menu .sub ul {display: block;}

#mega-menu-1 {
font: normal 13px Arial, sans-serif; 
list-style: none; 
position: relative; 
padding: 0; 
margin: 0;
}
#mega-menu-1 .sub ul {
display: block;
}
#mega-menu-1 {
background: #222; 
width: 100%; 
height: 40px;
position: relative;
}
#mega-menu-1 li {
float: left; 
margin: 0; 
padding: 0; 
font-weight: bold;
}
#mega-menu-1 li a {
float: left; 
display: block; 
color: #fff; 
padding: 12px 25px; 
background: #222; 
text-decoration: none;
}
#mega-menu-1 li.mega-hover a, #mega-menu-1 li.mega-hover a:hover {
background: #CCC; 
color: #000;
}
#mega-menu-1 li a:hover {
background: #999; 
color: #000;
}
#mega-menu-1 li .sub-container {
position: absolute;
}
#mega-menu-1 li .sub {
background: #efefef; 
padding: 15px; 
border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
#mega-menu-1 li .sub .row {
width: 100%; 
overflow: hidden;
clear: both;
}
#mega-menu-1 li .sub li {
list-style: none; 
float: none; 
width: 170px; 
font-size: 1em; 
font-weight: normal;
}
#mega-menu-1 li .sub li.mega-hdr {
margin: 0 10px 10px 0; 
float: left;
}
#mega-menu-1 li .sub li.mega-hdr.last {
margin-right: 0;
}
#mega-menu-1 li .sub a {
background: none; 
color: #111; 
padding: 7px 10px; 
display: block; 
float: none; 
font-size: 0.9em;
}
#mega-menu-1 li .sub li.mega-hdr a.mega-hdr-a {
padding: 5px 15px; 
margin-bottom: 5px; 
background: #6B6B6B; 
text-transform: uppercase; 
font-weight: bold; 
color: #fff;
}
#mega-menu-1 li .sub li.mega-hdr a.mega-hdr-a:hover {
color: #000;
}
#mega-menu-1 .sub li.mega-hdr li a {
padding: 4px 5px; 
font-weight: normal;
}
#mega-menu-1 .sub li.mega-hdr li a:hover {
color: #a32403; 
background: #efefef;
}
#mega-menu-1 .sub ul li {
padding-right: 0;
}
#mega-menu-1 li .sub-container.non-mega .sub {
padding: 10px;
}
#mega-menu-1 li .sub-container.non-mega li {
padding: 0; 
width: 190px; 
margin: 0;
}
#mega-menu-1 li .sub-container.non-mega li a {
padding: 7px 5px 7px 22px;
}
#mega-menu-1 li .sub-container.non-mega li a:hover {
color: #a32403; 
background: #efefef;
}
```

I have another file called green.css and the codes are below

```
.mega-menu ul, .mega-menu ul li {list-style: none;}
.mega-menu ul {position: relative; padding: 0; margin: 0;}
.mega-menu ul li ul {display: none;}
.mega-menu .sub {display: none;}
.mega-menu .sub ul {display: block;}

.green {font: normal 13px Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 16px;}
.green ul.mega-menu, .green ul.mega-menu, .green ul.mega-menu li {margin: 0; padding: 0; border: none;}
.green ul.mega-menu {background: #222 url(images/bg_green.png) repeat-x 0 -80px; width: 100%; height: 40px; border-right: 1px solid #44b3ff; border-left: 1px solid #44b3ff; position: relative;}
.green ul.mega-menu li {float: left; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold;}
.green ul.mega-menu li a {float: left; display: block; color: #000; padding: 12px 38px 12px 25px; background: url(images/bg_green.png) repeat-x 100% 0; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff; text-decoration: none;}
.green ul.mega-menu li a.dc-mega {position: relative;}
.green ul.mega-menu li a .dc-mega-icon {display: block; position: absolute; width: 8px; height: 6px;  top: 18px; right: 15px; background: url(images/arrow.png) no-repeat 0 100%;}
.green ul.mega-menu li.mega-hover a, .green ul.mega-menu li a:hover {background-position: 100% -40px; color: #000; text-shadow: none;}
.green ul.mega-menu li.mega-hover a .dc-mega-icon {background-position: 0 100%;}
.green ul.mega-menu li .sub-container {position: absolute; background: url(images/bg_sub_left.png) no-repeat 0 100%; padding-left: 20px; margin-left: -3px;}
.green ul.mega-menu li .sub {background: url(images/bg_sub.png) no-repeat 100% 100%; padding: 20px 20px 20px 10px;}
.green ul.mega-menu li .sub-container.mega .sub {padding: 20px 20px 10px 0;}
.green ul.mega-menu li .sub .row {width: 100%; overflow: hidden; clear: both;}
.green ul.mega-menu li .sub li {list-style: none; float: none; width: 170px; font-size: 1em; font-weight: normal;}
.green ul.mega-menu li .sub li.mega-hdr {margin: 0 10px 10px 0; float: left;}
.green ul.mega-menu li .sub li.mega-hdr.last {margin-right: 0;}
.green ul.mega-menu li .sub a {background: none; border: none; text-shadow: none; color: #111; padding: 7px 10px; display: block; float: none; text-decoration: none; font-size: 0.9em;}
.green ul.mega-menu li .sub li.mega-hdr a.mega-hdr-a {padding: 5px 5px 5px 15px; margin-bottom: 5px; background: #4EC3F3 url(images/bg_mega_hdr.png) no-repeat 0 0; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: bold; color: #000; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;}
.green ul.mega-menu li .sub li.mega-hdr a.mega-hdr-a:hover {color: #fff; text-shadow: none;}
.green ul.mega-menu .sub li.mega-hdr li a {padding: 4px 5px 4px 20px; background: url(images/arrow_off.png) no-repeat 5px 8px; font-weight: normal;}
.green ul.mega-menu .sub li.mega-hdr li a:hover {color: #a32403; background: #efefef url(images/arrow_on.png) no-repeat 5px 8px;}
.green ul.mega-menu .sub ul li {padding-right: 0;}
.green ul.mega-menu li .sub-container.non-mega .sub {padding: 20px 20px 20px 0;}
.green ul.mega-menu li .sub-container.non-mega li {padding: 0; width: 190px; margin: 0;}
.green ul.mega-menu li .sub-container.non-mega li a {padding: 7px 5px 7px 22px; background: url(images/arrow_off.png) no-repeat 7px 10px;}
.green ul.mega-menu li .sub-container.non-mega li a:hover {color: #a32403; background: #efefef url(images/arrow_on.png) no-repeat 7px 10px;}
```

Please suggest me how to solve this issue.. thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.green ul.mega-menu li a {
float: left;
display: block;
color: black;
padding: 12px 38px 12px 25px;
background: url(images/bg_green.png) repeat-x 100% 0;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px white;
text-decoration: none;
width: 102px;
text-align: center;
}
```

instead of the that you have already

and then a little jquery addon to remove the last splitter

```
$('.green ul.mega-menu li:last-child a').css('background','none');
```

**EDIT** for better looking buttons

```
.green ul.mega-menu li a .dc-mega-icon {
display: block;
position: absolute;
width: 8px;
height: 6px;
top: 18px;
right: 12%;
background: url(images/arrow.png) no-repeat 0 100%;
}
```

**EDIT REPLY use this following css**

```
.green {font: normal 13px Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 16px;}
.green ul.mega-menu, .green ul.mega-menu, .green ul.mega-menu li {margin: 0; padding: 0; border: none;}
.green ul.mega-menu {background: #222 url(images/bg_green.png) repeat-x 0 -80px; width: 100%; height: 40px; border-right: 1px solid #44b3ff; border-left: 1px solid #44b3ff; position: relative;}
.green ul.mega-menu li {float: left; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold;}
.green ul.mega-menu li a {float: left; display: block; color: black; padding: 12px 38px 12px 25px; background: url(images/bg_green.png) repeat-x 100% 0; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px white; text-decoration: none; width: 102px; text-align: center;}
.green ul.mega-menu li a.dc-mega {position: relative;}
.green ul.mega-menu li a .dc-mega-icon {display: block; position: absolute; width: 8px; height: 6px; top: 18px; right: 12%; background: url(images/arrow.png) no-repeat 0 100%;}
.green ul.mega-menu li.mega-hover a, .green ul.mega-menu li a:hover {background-position: 100% -40px; color: #000; text-shadow: none;}
.green ul.mega-menu li.mega-hover a .dc-mega-icon {background-position: 0 100%;}
.green ul.mega-menu li .sub-container {position: absolute; background: url(images/bg_sub_left.png) no-repeat 0 100%; padding-left: 20px; margin-left: -3px;}
.green ul.mega-menu li .sub {background: url(images/bg_sub.png) no-repeat 100% 100%; padding: 20px 20px 20px 10px;}
.green ul.mega-menu li .sub-container.mega .sub {padding: 20px 20px 10px 0;}
.green ul.mega-menu li .sub .row {width: 100%; overflow: hidden; clear: both;}
.green ul.mega-menu li .sub li {list-style: none; float: none; width: 170px; font-size: 1em; font-weight: normal;}
.green ul.mega-menu li .sub li.mega-hdr {margin: 0 10px 10px 0; float: left;}
.green ul.mega-menu li .sub li.mega-hdr.last {margin-right: 0;}
.green ul.mega-menu li .sub a {background: none; border: none; text-shadow: none; color: #111; padding: 7px 10px; display: block; float: none; text-decoration: none; font-size: 0.9em;}
.green ul.mega-menu li .sub li.mega-hdr a.mega-hdr-a {padding: 5px 5px 5px 15px; margin-bottom: 5px; background: #4EC3F3 url(images/bg_mega_hdr.png) no-repeat 0 0; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: bold; color: #000; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;}
.green ul.mega-menu li .sub li.mega-hdr a.mega-hdr-a:hover {color: #fff; text-shadow: none;}
.green ul.mega-menu .sub li.mega-hdr li a {padding: 4px 5px 4px 20px; background: url(images/arrow_off.png) no-repeat 5px 8px; font-weight: normal;}
.green ul.mega-menu .sub li.mega-hdr li a:hover {color: #a32403; background: #efefef url(images/arrow_on.png) no-repeat 5px 8px;}
.green ul.mega-menu .sub ul li {padding-right: 0;}
.green ul.mega-menu li .sub-container.non-mega .sub {padding: 20px 20px 20px 0;}
.green ul.mega-menu li .sub-container.non-mega li {padding: 0; width: 190px; margin: 0;}
.green ul.mega-menu li .sub-container.non-mega li a {padding: 7px 5px 7px 22px; background: url(images/arrow_off.png) no-repeat 7px 10px;}
.green ul.mega-menu li .sub-container.non-mega li a:hover {color: #a32403; background: #efefef url(images/arrow_on.png) no-repeat 7px 10px;}
```

[image: Image of how it should look]

Comment: I have added another file called green.css. can you please have a look on this. thns for ur support.

Comment: I have editted the file try to overwrite this section with yours in the green css so how its looking - how it should look(see my edit with the img at the bottom

Comment: wowwwwwwwwwwwwwwww many many many thanks dear.. its work fine.. Love you.. god bless you..

Comment: Dear do you see some of the button text are in two lines.. like if you click communities, "create communities" are in two lines.. can we make all this in one line

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
display: table;
```

to the ul and

```
display: table-cell;
```

to the lis instead of floating.

This would lead to something like:

```
.green ul.mega-menu {
    display: table;
}
.green ul.mega-menu li {
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
}
```

BTW: do you really think marquee is a good idea?

Comment: if not maquee u ahve any idea to attract people. ?? Do you means I have to chagne diplay to table cell ?? can u please send me the code

Comment: marquee doesn't attract people, it distracts.

Comment: I have added another file called green.css. can you please have a look on this. Also if you have any idea better then marquee please let me know which will attract users easily.

Comment: can u tell me alternative to marquee, Please.. I want people to see one pointsl