# drop down menu width alignment

Tags: html, css, menu

I have just posted my question before for the same topic which is [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13823284/drop-down-menu-width-arrangement). I got a correct answer from Mr. Simon, thanks to him. I found one more issue, the width of the drop down menu is very small and its not coming in one line please [Click Here](http://www.fedri.com/bh/) to know the detail. I want the text to come in one line...

Also, he said to use the below code to remove the last splitter in the menu filed. I dont know where to put this. Can you assist me.. Thanks..

```
$('.green ul.mega-menu li:last-child a').css('background','none');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your CSS:

```
.mega-menu a { white-space: nowrap; }
```

For second issue (width of nav items):

Remove the fixed width (and I would change `text-align: center` to `text-align: left`) on the following CSS declaration:

```
.green ul.mega-menu li a {
    background: url("images/bg_green.png") repeat-x scroll 100% 0 transparent;
    color: #000000;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 12px 38px 12px 25px;
    text-align: center; /* <--- Change this to text-align: left; */
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #FFFFFF;
    width: 102px; /* <--- Remove this */
}
```

Comment: Its working but if you please click "the Lounge" and if you move mouse over any links the hover color is limited and its not covering the full area. Any solution for this >>>

Comment: @user1820652 I've updated my answer to address your subsequent issue.

Comment: When I remove this width 102px all catagory comes close to each other. There is a space on the right side of the menu.